Binding a v-date-picker to a v-text-field with a formatted date
I am trying to bind a v-date-picker option to a v-text-field with the data formatted. I have a function I already use throughout my application called formateDate() and I am trying to apply this to the v-text-field value with the v-model of the datepicker as the input. When the v-menu loads and the initial value is loaded the v-text-field shows the formatted date but as soon as I select an option in the v-date-picker the value clears and nothing is shown. No errors are drawn either. Here is my code:
<v-menu v-model="ratingPeriodBeginMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="auto">
    
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-text-field
            v-bind="props"
            label="Rating Period Begin Date"
            :value="formatDate(ratingPeriodBeginModel,'MM/DD/YYYY')?.toString()"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
            variant="outlined"/>
    </template>
    
    <v-date-picker 
        v-model="ratingPeriodBeginModel"
        color="primary"
        no-title
        @input="ratingPeriodBeginMenu = false">
    </v-date-picker>
    
</v-menu>

And my function I utilize is as follows:
export function formatDate(inputDate : Date | null, formatType : string) {
    if(inputDate == null) return null;
    
    if(formatType == 'MM/DD/YYYY'){
        const date = new Date(inputDate)
        return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US")
    }
}


Are you working with vue2 / vuetify2 or vue3 / vuetify3 ? If you're in vuetify 3 try to replace the :value by :model-value on you're v-text-field

Vuetify 3. Not sure why but when I had tried that previously it did not work but for some reason now it does. If you put this as a response I will mark as the answer.

If you work with Vuetify 3 try to replace the :value of you're v-text-field by a :model-value :
<v-menu v-model="ratingPeriodBeginMenu"
    :close-on-content-click="false"
    transition="scale-transition"
    offset-y
    max-width="290px"
    min-width="auto">
    
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-text-field
            v-bind="props"
            label="Rating Period Begin Date"
            :model-value="formatDate(ratingPeriodBeginModel,'MM/DD/YYYY')?.toString()"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
            variant="outlined"/>
    </template>
    
    <v-date-picker 
        v-model="ratingPeriodBeginModel"
        color="primary"
        no-title
        @input="ratingPeriodBeginMenu = false">
    </v-date-picker>
    
</v-menu>


Why does vuetify 3 use model-value in its examples instead of v-model?

Because v-model is a two-way binding, in this case you juste want to show the value in you're text-field and the update is made by the v-date-picker (also, v-model don't allow a method as value)

Makes sense and thank you for that clarification. I also notice one other item related to this is @input="ratingPeriodBeginMenu = false" does not seem to do anything. Has that changed in vuetify 3 to not allow auto close on selection?

Try with : @update:modelValue="ratingPeriodBeginMenu = false"

I dont know why but I am struggling with figuring out what works in vuetify 3 vs vuetify 2 so thank you for that.
